# Ubuntu "trusty" mount smb share from Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: 14.04, samba, macosx

I work in a small shop that's entirely Mac based (with the occasional PC that shows up from time to time), and we've got a freelancer whose using Ubuntu "trusty" trying to access some files on our OS X Server running 10.11.6. SMB is enabled on the server, and Windows 10 clients have no issue accessing the shares over SMB, however, our Ubuntu user isn't able to connect.
I'm guessing this may have something to do with the NTLM setting on the Ubuntu client, but I'm not sure where to change that. Can anyone help out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1305827

Read towards the end.  It covers how El Capitan breaks smb compatibility